# Como podria cambiar este código en términos de async y await en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, async-await

Estoy utilizando mongoose para poder realizar una conexión entre Mongo y Node, quiero saber si existe alguna forma de cambiar este código asíncrono en términos de async y await sin utilizar Promesas.

```
function getOrders (orderId){ 
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    let filter = {};
    if (orderId){
        filter ={orders: orderId}
    }

    Model.find(filter)
        .populate('client')
        .exec(function (err, populated) {
            console.log(populated);
            resolve(populated)
        });
})
```

}

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor edita tu pregunta y traduce el título al Castellano, igualmente elimina la parte que tienes en inglés en el cuerpo de tu pregunta. Recuerda que estás en la versión en Español del sitio, por lo tanto debes usar Castellano como único idioma para preguntas/respuestas. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [`find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), ofrece un método [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/then), y por lo tanto puede ser usado ***como*** una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise). Sin embargo, [no devuelve una promesa](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises).

Para convertir o cambiar tu código para usar `async await` puedes envolver tu consulta en una función `async` y usar directamente `await` sobre la consulta, sin necesidad de envolver la misma en una Promesa:

```js
// declaro mi función como async
function async getOrders (orderId){ 
  let filter = {};
  if (orderId){
    filter = {orders: orderId}
  }
  // siempre que se trabaje con Promesas se debe usar un bloque try catch
  try {
    let results = await Model.find(filter).populate('client').exec(); // llamamos al método exec() sin argumentos
    console.log(results);
    // ...
    // hacemos cosas con el resultado
    // ...
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    // ...
    // manejamos el error
    // ...
  }
}
```

Otra aproximación es crear una función envoltorio que devuelve una Promesa, y usar los métodos `.then()` y `.catch()` para resolver o rechazar la Promesa, o hacerlo dentro de la función `callback` que pasas al método `.exec()`, sin embargo en mi opinón es escribir demasiado código para hacer la misma tarea que muestro en el ejemplo anterior.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.

Comment: Gracias, ahora lo tengo todo muy claro. 
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que cuando quieras llamar a esta funcion tambien es bueno agregar un await  para que todo ll
Algo como esto:

```
async miFuncion(){
    let orderId;
    await this.getOrders(orderId);
  }


   getOrders (orderId){ 
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
        let filter = {};
        if (orderId){
            filter ={orders: orderId}
        }

       await this.Model.find(filter)
            .populate('client')
            .exec(async function (err, populated) {
                console.log(populated);
               await resolve(populated)
            });
    })
  }
```

Comment: Olvidas algo importante: cuando se trabaja con [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) en Javascript, se debe usar un bloque `try catch`. Saludos

Comment: Otra cosa que se me escapa, el OP desea escribir el código usando `async await` sin necesidad de utilizar una Promesa. En tu respuesta (correcta), usas una Promesa, por lo tanto creo que no se ajusta a lo que pregunta el OP. Saludos